# Building a string in Clojure with recursion

Tags: loops, recursion, clojure

I need to generate a random char and build a string and only stop when my string contains the newly generated char.

```
(defn rand-char [len]
  (apply str (take len (repeatedly #(char (+ (rand 26) 65))))))

(def random-string
  (loop [x (rand-char 1)
         result []]
    (if (some #(= x %) result)
      (apply str (conj result x))
      (recur (conj result x) (x (rand-char 1))))))
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand-char` returns a `string` but in `(x (rand-char 1))` you're attempting to call `x` as a function, hence the error. You only need to call `rand-char` to generate the next random string to try. The arguments to `recur` should be in the same order as those declared in the `loop` so yours are in the wrong order:

```
(recur (rand-char 1) (conj result x))
```

Comment: @rake-write-code - Do you want `random-string` to be a function? At the moment you're using `def` so it's being evaluated to a vector. `(random-string)` is trying to call the vector as a function. Vectors are functions from an index to the corresponding value e.g. `([1 2 3] 0) => 1` so you get the error because you haven't supplied enough arguments. It looks like you should defined `random-string` using `defn` e.g. `(defn random-string [] ...)`.

Comment: Hi @lee, Thanks for all the pointers, it is supposed to be a method and I've been able to run it by just passing 0 as a parameter. I have been able to print a correct string but I want it returned instead and it evaluates to a null reference.

`(def random-string
  (loop [x (rand-char 1)
         result ""]
    (if (.contains result x)
      (println (str result x))
      (recur (rand-char 1) (str result x)))))`

but I don't want to print it but instead return it. just returning `(str result x)` says java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  .

Comment: Thanks for your help @lee, I got it. I just needed to pass a vector to the function when I define it.

Answer (score 1):

something like this does it serve you?

```
(defn random-string []
  (loop [x (rand-char 1)
         result []]
    (if (.contains result x)
      (apply str result)
      (recur (rand-char 1) (conj result x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already accepted Lee's answer, I have since also opted to build result directly as a string.